# Arduino code doesn't work after including my C libraries

Tags: c, arduino

I wrote a library in C and I m trying to use it now in Arduino. The C code on Codeblocks works fine even on Arduino I don't get compilation errorS. However after including the header in Arduino even Serial.print() stopped showing anything on the serial monitor.
So why this is happening?
Here is the code i m not even testing any of the library fonctions:

```
#include <IdentificationModule.h>
#include <MangementModule.h>
#include <SupFunctions.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
// uint8_t b=4;
Serial.print( "Test");

}

void loop() {


}
```

[image]

Comment: `So why this is happening?` 1. you use too much ram or your code is too large and arduino does not even upload it to the device. 2. Have something wrong in your headers.

Comment: i removed some code and it woked like you said myabe it was too large. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Go to File>Preferences

in the line containing

```
Show Verbose output during
```

Select the checkbox for compilation.

Then add a line anywhere in your code (Ensuring that the added line does not cause compilation errors) and re-compile the code.

You should see warnings and errors that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did what  PeterJ_01 said to me i removed some unecessary inludes in source code now that Serial.print( "Test"); works but whn i test the library i get undefind reference error

Answer (score 0):

You should show us you source files. If it compiles well (are you sure of that) there is no apparent reason not to work. Unless you are modifying something of the Arduino core on you files.

Comment: I removed some includes from the source code now that Serial.print() works but when i try to use a function from the source code i get undefined reference   erro ......Noting i know bitRead existes in arduino but i need ton use this code out of arduino to

Answer (score 0):

First of all maybe my probleme was kind of my code was too large too large and arduino does not even upload it to the device because when i removed some of the unecessary **inludce** that **Serial.print( "Test")** worked.
After that when I tried to test the library fonctions I get **"undefined reference to"** But strangely when I changed the extinction of the source code from **".c"** to **".cpp"** it worked !!!